# Question about limit points with continuous maps. What have I done wrong?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm trying to do this exercise:

> Suppose that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous. If $x$ is a limit point of the subset $A$ of $X$, is it necessarily true that $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$?

I'm having a somewhat hard time wrapping my head around topology, and I know that it is not necessarily true, but I want to know exactly what I've misunderstood because I "showed" that it is true.

In Munkres there is a theorem stating that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous then for each $x \in X$ and each neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x)$, there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U) \subset V$. Assume there is some $V \subset Y$ which is a neighbourhood of $f(x)$, and also because we assume that $x$ is a limit point of $A$ in $X$, the open set $U$ in the theorem must intersect $A$ in some point $y \neq x$. Since $f(U) \subset V$ then $f(y) \in V$, so every neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x)$ intersects $f(A)$ in $f(y) \in f(A)$, and then $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$.

Now onto why I'm wrong. Is it because there doesn't necessarily exist a neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x)$? Is it because while $y \neq x$ in $X$ it could be the case that $f(x) = f(y)$?

Comment: No. For a counterexample, let $f$ be a constant function.

Comment: The fact that every neighbourhood of $f(x)$ meets $f(A)$ only means that $f(x)$ is an adherent point of $f(A)$, not that it is a limit point.

Comment: What do you mean by adherent point?

Comment: "Adherent point of X" seems to correspond to "a point in the closure of X" in Munkres' terms.

Comment: FWIW, many people do not distinguish between limit points and adherent points.

Answer (score 2):

Using $y \neq x$ implies $f(x) \neq f(y)$ will definitely break your proof because it's only true for injective functions and you haven't assumed anything about $f$.